# SQL: how do I add multiple rows together to produce a new row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add rows together and produce a new row at the bottom of the table.

In the example below I want to add up US, Canada, and Mexico's population and add a new row to the table (see arrow, and red cell below).

[image]

In Excel this is simply a case using the SUM function, but how do I do this in SQL? When I use `sum(population)` this produces a new column - but I need it as a row.

At the moment my solution is to create a new table with the population column aggregated, and then `UNION ALL` to my original table. Not very elegant I think you'll admit.

There has to be a way to do it with SQL without using `UNION ALL`?

Thanks

Comment: You might look at the ROLLUP option, but really issues of data display are best resolved in application code.

Comment: You wouldn't add such a row to a table.  It would throw off users who use the table.  Instead, you would just calculate it when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use roll  up

```
SELECT country, sum(Population)  as Population
FROM your_table
group by country 
WITH ROLLUP;
```

or use a union

```
SELECT country, sum(Population)  as Population
FROM  your_table 
group by country
union 
SELECT "North America region", SUM( Population ) as Population
FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following SQL insert Query.

```
Insert into TABLE_NAME (Country, Population) 
values ('North American Region', (select sum(Population) from TABLE_NAME));
```

You must change the `TABLE_NAME` to your Table's name, and use the column values correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to do some of similar

```
INSERT INTO T( country, popolation )
SELECT "North America region" as country, SUM( Population ) as Population
FROM T
WHERE country in ('US','Canada','Mexico')
```